# How to install 'add-apt-repository' using the terminal?

Tags: software-installation, add-apt-repository

I want to install:

```
add-apt-repository ppa:ricotz/testin
```

It is showing:

```
The program add-apt-repository is currently not installed.
You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install python-software-properties
```

What should I do now?

Comment: sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ricotz/testin

Comment: The program 'add-apt-repository' is currently not installed.  You can install it by typing:
apt-get install python-software-properties

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu you are using?

Comment: just copyy and paste the command its telling you to do bruh...

Comment: [`add-apt-repository`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/add-apt-repository.1.html) is provided by `software-properties-common`  [see filelist](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/all/software-properties-common/filelist)

Answer (score 239):

Try these:

```
sudo apt-get install software-properties-common
```

and/or

```
sudo apt-get install python3-software-properties
```

and/or

```
sudo apt-get install python-software-properties
```

Comment: sudo apt-get install python3-software-properties                                        show this below                                                                                                  Package python3-software-properties is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'python3-software-properties' has no installation candidate

Comment: sudo apt-get install software-properties-common.  shows  software-properties-common is already the newest version

Comment: it show when i try to install "add-apt-repository ppa:ricotz/testing "
The program 'add-apt-repository' is currently not installed.  You can install it by typing:
apt-get install python-software-properties

Comment: Which Ubuntu version are you running?

Comment: `apt-get install software-properties-common` seems to be enough in Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: tested this on a docker image. `software-properties-common` and `python-software-properties` were required

Comment: [`add-apt-repository`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/add-apt-repository.1.html) is provided by `software-properties-common`  [see filelist](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/all/software-properties-common/filelist)

Comment: Tested on new Debian, also software-properties-common and python-software-properties were required

Comment: `ubuntu:latest` docker image gives `E: Unable to locate package software-properties-common`

Comment: If it's `Unable to locate package`, make sure to `apt-get update` first.

Comment: In docker's `ubuntu:latest` works after `apt update` and installing `software-properties-common`