# Upgrade problem with add repositories and ubuntu software center

Tags: 14.04, apt, updates, software-center

I want to Update my OS, Ubuntu 14.04 and I have problems with *Ubuntu Software Center* and add repositories for install more apps.

the command:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:elementary-os/unstable-upstream
sudo: add-apt-repository: command not found
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to install 'add-apt-repository' using the terminal?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/493460/how-to-install-add-apt-repository-using-the-terminal)

Comment: If you really want to try elementary os, I'd recommend you to install it instead of using a third party repository.

Comment: try "apt-add-repository" instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply run

```
sudo apt-get install software-properties-common
```

And you'll have `add-apt-repository`

The package is part of the [Ubuntu standard repositories](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/software-properties-common).